# Questions on aggregation

Tags: sql

I am required to find the name of the product  (iname) where total delivery quantity is equal to the total sales quantity

Two tables given are

```
sale:
snum:sqty:iname
1   :3   :Shoes
2   :1   :Shoes
3   :1   :Hat        

delivery:
dnum:dqty:iname
1   :5   :Shoes
2   :1   :Hat
3   :3   :Shoes
```

I tried this code but the result I got is aggregated incorrectly because there are multiple sales and deliveries of the same item

```
select sale.iname
from sale
inner join delivery
on sale.iname = delivery.iname
group by sale.iname
having sum(delivery.dqty) - sum(sale.sqty) = 0
```

When I do the following I was able to find the correct total quantity but is there a way I can do this in one code?

```
select iname, sum(sqty)
from sale
group by iname

select iname, sum(dqty)
from delivery
group by iname
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select a.iname,saleQty,deliveryQty
from
(
select iname, sum(sqty) as saleQty
from sale
group by iname
)A inner join 
(
select iname, sum(dqty) as deliveryQty
from delivery
group by iname
)B on A.iname=B.iname where saleQty-deliveryQty=0
```

Comment: I don't quite understand how the A and B work. Are you creating temporary tables to join them?

Comment: @sammytummy, not a temp table , it's a subquery

Answer (score 0):

You can use your aggregation queries as subqueries in the `from` clause.  I would phrase this as:

```
select s.iname, s.saleQty, d.deliveryQty
from (select iname, sum(sqty) as saleQty
      from sale s
      group by iname
     ) s inner join 
     (select iname, sum(dqty) as deliveryQty
      from delivery d
      group by iname
     ) d
     on d.iname = s.iname and
        d.saleQty = s.deliveryQty;
```